Problems making payments with Opayo from Elavon
We’re currently having problems with the DIRECT integration of Elavon’s Opayo systems. Specifically it’s about making normal payments on the TEST environment; strangely, the LIVE environment with the same code is working fine for us.
We’ve never had any significant issues before now and have been using the service for many years now.
The issue seems to be specifically surrounding the changes they’ve imposed on the various integrations and the hostnames used in the URLs, moving from their old sagepay.com domain to the new elavon.com hostnames:

(test environment) test.sagepay.com -> sandbox.opayo.eu.elavon.com
(live environment) live.sagepay.com -> live.opayo.eu.elavon.com

Our rough timeline of events looks something like this:

Prior to March 2024: Received the numerous warning emails about changes to the hostnames
6th March 2024: tested the new URL changes on our staging environment and confirmed it was working correctly, released to our live/production environment the same day
Around 8th April 2024: one of the team members noticed that he was unable to make even a simple (non-3DS challenged payment) on our test/staging environment any more, nor on his local development environment which also uses the new test URLs
Up until 10th April 2024: Various tests/checks and attempts to fix (assuming the issue was on our end), but to no avail we sent our first support email to Elavon
After 10th April 2024: It’s been back and forth with Opayo product support, we’ve double-checked we’re doing everything with regards to their migration guide here: https://www.elavon.co.uk/resource-center/news-and-insights/opayo-url-migration-faq.html

The response we get back from their system looks like the sort of response a web application firewall (WAF) would return and the response is from “AkamaiGhost” and looks pretty much like this: https://community.akamai.com/customers/s/article/Why-is-Akamai-blocking-me?language=en_US
It's important to note that the test environment must have been working for us prior to releasing these changes to our production environment, but something has since stopped working/blocked us on the test environment.
For our local development environments, we’ve checked our IP reputation and that’s apparently not an issue: https://www.akamai.com/us/en/clientrep-lookup/
So would you also agree that for some reason their Akamai WAF/security policies are blocking us before we get a typical key-value Opayo payment response?
Support are saying it’s “only us” that are experiencing this issue and I guess that could technically be the case if we were being caught with their WAF where other customers are not.
The infrastructure between the old and new URLs is definitely separate/distinct; if we run the exact same code after switching only the URLs back to the old one’s then payments work absolutely fine.
And as I’ve mentioned at the beginning, production payments with our code are working, but test environment payments are not, which again would make sense, if they’ve maybe got a more aggressive blocking policy on their test environment compared to the live environment.
We’re not doing anything which would be considered abusive (e.g., pentesting, things that would cause a rate-limiter to go off etc.)
It would be good to hear from you if someone:

Is having the same issue and how it presents
Has solved the issue
Has had a similar AkamaiGhost block issue like this (not necessarily to do with Elavon/Opayo) and if you solved it, how that was achieved

We’re keen to get this sorted as even though we’re able to make payments on production without issue our staging environment needs to work so we’re able to adequately test before we release into production.

Yes, we are seeing something similar, and Opayo have reported it may be down to the cyphers when updating to the new url's. We only experienced this on the new urls, whereby it randomly returns 403's on the live environment only, for a random period between 5 mins - 2 hours; happening around 5 times per week.

We have seen the same issue and have been challenging opayo support for about a month. So far they insist the issue is Cipher related which I have demonstrated many times this is not the case. Responses from there 1st and 2nd line support are the same there is little actual help other than “we support fewer ciphers check your selection and support”.
I can 100% replicate the issue. You can switch the Urls from sagepay to Elavon then successfully register a transaction and get the standard responses from the payment endpoint, then after a few hours this stops and the Akamai Edgesuite steps in and 401 the requests. You can after about a week or so they try again, at that point you will be allowed to register successfully for another few hours before the issue returns.
I have tried a number of servers builds ciphers and the result is the same, at one point they were suggesting the ciphers on the webservice our side for SSL notification url in the payment transaction was the issue; which I still don’t understand and I think demonstrates their lack of knowledge on the process of making a web request. That said I addressed the issue and to no surprise it made no difference.
The response from Akamai contains a link to there diagnostics  for more information which I have passed to Opayo support asking for feedback or the corresponding report. So far Opayo support have not acknowledged this in their responses, so I wonder if they are even aware of this layer of infrastructure they have in place.
We support a number of Opayo users and can demonstrate it on any of the accounts we manage.
We are in the process of lining up an alternative solution as there is little to no faith in the support, other than they respond politely and within their SLA.
I have made a point of telling them we really want to make this work and find out what it is about our requests that triggers the protective 401. That said I have attempted to replicate the code base with manual curl requests and the effect is the same.
At the moment its pretty much radio silence.. I’m glad I’m not the only one!

Hi Leigh,
Thank you for taking the time to confirm we are not alone in having the same problems with the Opayo test environment. Certainly we've never had any issues making payments before this innocent "URL change" task. If I had to hazard a guess it's actually a bigger behind the scenes infrastructure consolidation task.

Hi Dan, No problem. Worth noting we are seeing it on the production urls too.

So an update from Opayo...

So an update from Opayo... They are now telling us that we are Webscraping them and are being blocked. Suggesting that vendors do this to check service availablity and telling us to stop it and the problem will go away.  Unfortunately we do no such thing and only make requests to opayo when we need a payment. I've requested a report of the scrapping requests the only positive I'm taking from this is they have moved on from suggesting we are using the wrong TLS1.3 or that we are using http. Still we are being blamed for the issue with no viable solution.

Thanks for the updates Leigh, I really appreciate it. I will follow up on our case tomorrow and let you know what they say, but all I've had in calls is "no progress, your case is with the 'service delivery team' and thanks for all the technical info you've provided us... also no ETA on a fix". All extremely frustrating.

Leigh, I called just now and apparently there is a "deadline extension spreadsheet" which if you were worried about the end of May deadline in relation to this, you can ask to be added to it. So although this is now with their technical teams, apparently we no longer have to worry about the cut-off deadline at the end of the month. HTH.

Hi Dan, Interestingly I have also had an update and this one is viable solution which I hope works. They have amended there WAF to reduce the risk of the IP being blocked. I'm going to give it a go.

Hi Leigh, thanks for the update. I'll try and give them a call in the next day or two and ask for the same. It sounds like they finally accept it's a WAF issue their end, although a little unnerving that they're now whitelisting IPs on-demand, as it implies they probably haven't got to the bottom of why their WAF is being set off simply by using it! (i.e., it's not like we've been pen-testing, load-testing their API)

Hi Dan, just confirming we are over a week without issue, so there solution looks to have worked. Hope it is resolved you as well. thanks

Thanks for checking in Leigh, no resolution yet, but we're hoping to have it resolved soon.
